Apple Status 21002
I am trying to validate my in-app purchase receipt, but I keep getting the 21002 error from Apple, which indicates that the receipt data is either malformed or missing. I've ensured that my shared secret is correct because this code used to work before I refactored it to handle subscription purchases.
I’m running Firebase Functions for receipt validation, and everything looks correct based on the Apple documentation, but 21002 keeps coming back. Here’s the setup:

iOS App: Handles the purchase and sends the receipt data.
Firebase Functions: Processes the receipt and forwards it to Apple's servers for validation.

Can anyone point out what might be causing this error?
Below are snippets of my Swift and Node.js code:
func purchaseSubscription() async {
    let productID = subscriptionPlan.subscriptionApplePriceId
    guard !productID.isEmpty else {
        print("Product ID is not set for the selected subscription plan.")
        await updateUI(with: "Product ID is not set for the selected subscription plan.", isPurchasing: false)
        return
    }

    do {
        if let product = try await StoreKitManager.shared.fetchProduct(withIdentifier: productID) {
            if let transaction = try await StoreKitManager.shared.purchase(product: product) {
                if let receiptData = fetchReceiptData() {
                    await validateReceiptAndHandleResponse(receiptData: receiptData, subscriptionPlan: subscriptionPlan)
                } else {
                    await updateUI(with: "Unable to fetch receipt data.", isPurchasing: false)
                }
            } else {
                await updateUI(with: "Purchase failed: Transaction could not be completed.", isPurchasing: false)
            }
        } else {
            await updateUI(with: "Product not found", isPurchasing: false)
        }
    } catch {
        print("Error fetching product: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        await updateUI(with: "Purchase failed: \(error.localizedDescription)", isPurchasing: false)
    }
}

func fetchReceiptData() -> String? {
    guard let receiptUrl = Bundle.main.appStoreReceiptURL,
          let receiptData = try? Data(contentsOf: receiptUrl, options: .alwaysMapped) else {
        print("Receipt not found.")
        return nil
    }
    print("Receipt data size: \(receiptData.count) bytes")
    return receiptData.base64EncodedString()
}

func validateReceiptAndHandleResponse(receiptData: String, subscriptionPlan: SubscriptionPlan) async {
    let result = await firebaseFunctions.testAppleReceipt(receiptData: receiptData)
    
    switch result {
    case .success(let response):
        print("Receipt validation response: \(response)")
    case .failure(let error):
        print("Receipt validation failed: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
}

func testAppleReceipt(receiptData: String) async -> Result<[String: Any], Error> {
    let data: [String: Any] = ["receiptData": receiptData]
    
    do {
        let result = try await functions.httpsCallable("testAppleReceipt").call(data)
        if let response = result.data as? [String: Any] {
            return .success(response)
        } else {
            return .failure(NSError(domain: "Invalid Response", code: -1, userInfo: [NSLocalizedDescriptionKey: "No valid data received from backend."]))
        }
    } catch {
        print("Error calling testAppleReceipt function: \(error)")
        return .failure(error)
    }
}

const appleSandboxURL = "https://sandbox.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt";
const APPLE_SHARED_SECRET = functions.config().apple.shared_secret;

exports.testAppleReceipt = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
  const { receiptData } = data;
  
  console.log("Receipt data sent to Apple:", receiptData);

  const requestBody = {
    "receipt-data": receiptData,
    "password": APPLE_SHARED_SECRET,
    "exclude-old-transactions": true
  };

  try {
    const response = await fetch(appleSandboxURL, {
      method: "POST",
      body: JSON.stringify(requestBody),
      headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" }
    });

    if (!response.ok) {
      console.error("Error in receipt validation request:", response.status, response.statusText);
      return { error: "Failed to validate receipt" };
    }

    const result = await response.json();
    console.log("Apple Receipt Validation Response:", result);
    return result;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error occurred during receipt validation:", error);
    return { error: "An error occurred during receipt validation" };
  }
});


The verify receipt endpoint is deprecated.  You should either use on-device validation or, better yet, adopt Store Kit 2 as the original Store Kit API is also deprecated
